# Converting MODIS LAI data (2001) from HDF to GeoTIFF?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, geotiff-tiff, convert, modis

I am trying to convert MODIS Leaf Area Index (LAI) data from .hdf to GeoTiff from 2001.

I can successfully convert it using R for the more recent datasets using the following code:

```
library(gdalUtils)
sds <- get_subdatasets("GLASS01B01.V03.A2014001.2016025.hdf")
gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset = "GLASS01B01.V03.A2014001.2016025.tif")
```

Datasets from 2014 are available here: ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/GLASS/LAI/MODIS/0.05D/2014/.
I am then displaying the output GeoTIFF files in ArcGIS.

However, the result is incorrect for the data from 2001, available here:
ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/GLASS/LAI/MODIS/0.05D/2001/

The spatial extent information seems to be incorrect. The spatial extent is specified within the files as Top: 0.025, Left: -0.05, Right: 0.05, Bottom: -0.025

For datasets from 2014, projected correctly the spatial extent is specified as Top: 90, Left: -180, Right: 180, Bottom: -90.

I have also tried the HEGTool.

Can I correct for this, either in R or in ArcGIS? Maybe some addition to the code will allow me to specify the extent?

Answer (score 1):

In ArcGIS Desktop use the [Raster To Other Format](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-other-format.htm) for converting from `.hdf` to `.tif`.

Here is one example using first file from 2001: ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/GLASS/LAI/MODIS/0.05D/2001/

[image]